# Possible to take whitespace into account with prettify symbols? (without removing whitespace)

Tags: prettify-symbols-mode

With a C like language, it might be nice to be able to display:
 `(var * t)` as `(var x t)` - using the unicode multiply symbol.

However this causes problems with casting. eg:
`void fn(MyStruct *s)` becomes `void fn(MyStruct xs)`.

Is there a way to only replace a symbol when its surrounded by white-space? <sup>1</sup>

Matching `" * "` works but removes the spaces on either side.

---

1. Am aware spacing in this context is just a convention, nevertheless, would be interested to know if its possible.

Comment: If you write your own font-lock rule, you can match `" \\(\\*\\) "` and supply a "face expression" that apply `compose-region` as a side effect to match number 1. Note that the face expression should return `nil`. (If anybody want to write up an answer based on this, feel free to do so.)